# Install Django using setup file in Python 2.7

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to install Diango via setup up file then it shows the following error:

```
hari@hari-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/django-master$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 32, in <module>
    version = __import__('django').get_version()
  File "/home/hari/Downloads/django-master/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/hari/Downloads/django-master/django/utils/version.py", line 60, in <module>
    @functools.lru_cache()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Use pip to install django!

Comment: It happens with pip too. The problem is Django 2 doesn't work on Python 2.7. Either use Python 3 with Django 2, or use Django 1.11 with Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the zip file from github is only for windows, but i see that you are using linux so:

1) Use PIP (Use sudo as you are not inside virtualenv)

```
sudo pip install Django==1.10.6
```

2) Use GIT

```
git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when install Diango
then I use this in cmd

```
>>>> import functools  
>>> dir(functools)
['WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS', 'WRAPPER_UPDATES', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__'
, '__name__', '__package__', 'cmp_to_key', 'partial', 'reduce', 'total_ordering'
, 'update_wrapper', 'wraps']
```

you can see there is not lru_cache..so, I think this is the reason..
then I installed Python3.6.1

```
>>> import functools
>>> dir(functools)
['MappingProxyType', 'RLock', 'WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS', 'WRAPPER_UPDATES', 'WeakKey
Dictionary', '_CacheInfo', '_HashedSeq', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__'
, '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_
c3_merge', '_c3_mro', '_compose_mro', '_convert', '_find_impl', '_ge_from_gt', '
_ge_from_le', '_ge_from_lt', '_gt_from_ge', '_gt_from_le', '_gt_from_lt', '_le_f
rom_ge', '_le_from_gt', '_le_from_lt', '_lru_cache_wrapper', '_lt_from_ge', '_lt
_from_gt', '_lt_from_le', '_make_key', 'cmp_to_key', 'get_cache_token', 'lru_cache', 'namedtuple', 'partial', 'partialmethod', 'recursive_repr', 'reduce', 'sing
ledispatch', 'total_ordering', 'update_wrapper', 'wraps']
```

you can see lru_cache there,  I wish it's helpful for you (sorry for my English, I'm not good at this..)